# Solr: Document & sub-document level security

Tags: search, solr

I have a rather very know Solr issue.  The index contain a group of docs of employee records that has a set of public access fields and a set of secure fields.  Based on the user's security credentials (which may be indexed in the doc as one field), if a document matched, all its public fields and some of the secured fields which he has access.  This list of secure fields varies document to document in the same index. Example: a manage of a department (belonging to one company) can view all secure fields of employees (doc) under him but not for those who do not work under him (whether in the same company or not).  But he can still see ALL the public fields of ALL the of the employees (matched and filtered docs).

So being manager, I can see all (public + secure) fields of every one working under me but my asst can see only some of the secure fields who are under him.  How to implement this in Solr. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity) states that Solr does not concern itself with security at the document level.

Solr is designed to be an index of your data, not a replacement for your database (Access control is an important DB feature, only adds complexity to an index)

My suggestions:

1. **Remove all sensitive data from the index**. Each Solr document could include a reference (or link) to a 3rd party system/database holding the sensitive data requiring access control.
2. **Encrypt the sensitive content within the index** Using public/private key encryption, you can control who is able to decrypt the sensitive fields of a Solr document. (This solution wouldn't scale very well, nor does it allow searching of encrypted fields)
3. **Create a sensitive search index, for each manager**: Use the web server's authentication mechanism to control access to the index and load sensitive data there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take the following steps:

1. separate out the public and secure content, you can use two separate cores.
2. add a ServletFilter that sits between User and SOLR webapp and then you can use some basic ACL based security on top of SOLR results to filter out the content as per your application requirements.